In Japanese, "difficult to hear" in "The story was difficult to hear" is often expressed using/by "unbearable to listen to"

(1) In Japanese, "difficult to hear" in "The story was difficult to
hear" is often expressed using unbearable to listen to. [my
sentence]

I assume that my sentence is correct, but is it better to replace using with by?

(2) In Japanese, "difficult to hear" in "The story was difficult to
hear" is often expressed by unbearable to listen to.

DeepL, which is considered an excellent translator by many Japanese learners of English, uses by rather than using.
Google Translate uses as rather than using.
DeepL and Google Translate usually produce better Japanese-English translations than I do, hence my question.
[Edit] I now think that as might sound the most idiomatic to native speakers of English.

'Using' and 'by' are equally good; neither is 'better'. Also, 'difficult' is less extreme than 'unbearable'. Also, you claim that 'unbearable to listen to' is Japanese, which it very plainly is not.

Yes, you could also say "rendered as { }" or "rendered with a phrase that translates to {_}".

[After edit] I don't think that 'as' is any more idiomatic than the previous two.

Translation is not an exact science.

@TimR. Thank you very much, TimR. Your proposed phrase "rendered with a phrase that translates to {____}" is what I have been looking for. Unfortunately, my favorite English language forum, which is very beginner-friendly, has stopped working, but most of your comments/answers are as excellent as those I received at that forum. As a physically handicapped self-learner, I immensely appreciate all the help that I have received from you.

@MichaelHarvey Agreed, not more idiomatic. They're all valid options.

BTW, "difficult to listen to", though commonly used, is ambiguous. It could mean there's poor audio reproduction, or it could mean it's emotionally painful. My choice would be "distressing", "disturbing", or "painful", if that is the intent, (rather than a bad MP3 file).
